# Cocos2d 2.0 landscape orientation : howto?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a basic cocos2d app from the cocos2d template and cannot get it to work in landscape mode. 
I did read a lot of messages here and on cocos2d forums but no solution works.

My app start in landscape mode but everything is drawn sideways (sprites, labels, ...)

I updated the orientation in the project panel (updating info.plist automatically)...

I probably have to add something in me AppDelegate.m file (in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method) to tell the director to draw everything the right way.

https://gist.github.com/iesta/5143096

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Just make the app only support landscape orientation in it's Info.plist and it's view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Put these code in AppDelegate.mm

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication*)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow*)window
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
       return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Also select landscape in Xcode summary screen.
[image]

UPDATES: Got your mistake, you added Default-Portrait~ipad.png image instead of Default-Landscape~ipad.png .

Here is working source: [Download](https://www.box.com/s/6qi5urcv4p1ue8kwnhzu)

See this worked after changing default image.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not change anything... :(

Comment: Here is mu AppDelegate.m https://gist.github.com/5143431.git Actually it is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Got your mistake...U added portrait default image...replace it with landscape one.

Comment: Thank you! But the labels are still vertical. I think something must be done at the cocos2d level or not...

Answer (score 0):

Guys try to add this line to the appddelegate

[window_ setRootViewController:navController_];